# How to make Resizable Panels? 

Tags: jquery, css

I need to build a page that looks like Mac Mail or an Outlook Inbox. where the one page has a top panel and a bottom panel, and there is a divider in between that you can use to re-size, to either make a panel higher or shorter.

What's the standard jQuery/CSS technique for accomplishing this? I've never done this before so I am interested in your suggestions or any surprises that you might have encountered before.

Comment: you may want to dig into the code on jsfiddle.net's website

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery UI offers this as a plugin. Very simple and it really works well. I always use it. Here is the link with instructions:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable

Answer (score 23):

There are a few jQuery plugins that can do something like this. I think this [jQuery Splitter](http://www.methvin.com/splitter/) plugin is what you are looking for though.

Comment: This relies on an old version of JQuery.  I tried with 1.8.2 and it throws exceptions due to curCSS being removed in 1.8.0.  All examples on the splitter site are built against JQuery 1.3

Comment: The jquery.Splitter plugin relies on $.browser, which has been deprecated since 1.3 and removed entirely in 1.9.

Answer (score 5):

I believe something like this will serve your needs:
http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/10/23/javascript-splitters-and-resizable-panels/

There are several plugins referenced that mimic that UI.