# Looking to create slidable/dragable areas for a new webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to create a web page with two sections or columns, that a user a will be able to drag/slide; similar to the areas found in https://jsfiddle.net.

So far my research hasn't come up with anything, can anyone point me to a tutorial or similar? I would imagine I would have to use JavaScript or jQuery as well as CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call them panels, a quick google search brought me to this: https://github.com/allpro/layout/ ([demo](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/demos/simple.html)).

Also see these stackoverflow questions:

- [A full page layout with resizable panes using jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784574/a-full-page-layout-with-resizable-panes-using-jquery-ui)
- [How to make Resizable Panels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149294/how-to-make-resizable-panels)
- [How to make HTML element resizable using pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/how-to-make-html-element-resizable-using-pure-javascript)